# After refresh the page status jump back to 0 again How can I fix that

Tags: ajax, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

m try to create a simple social network

in my friend.vue file there is a ajax request like below

```
accept_friend() {
                this.loading = true
                this.$http.get('/accept_friend/' + this.profile_user_id)
                    .then( (response) =>{
                        //console.log(response)
                        if(response.body == 1){
                            this.status = 'friends'
                            this.loading = false
                        }
                    })
            }
```

route like below

```
Route::get('/accept_friend/{id}', 'FriendshipsController@accept_friend')->name('accept_friend');
```

and controller like below

```
public function accept_friend($id) {

        return Auth::user()->accept_friend($id);
    }
```

and there is trait

```
public function accept_friend($requester) {

        if ($this->has_pending_friend_request_from($requester) === 0) {

            return 0;
        }

        $friendship = Friendship::where('requester', $requester)
            ->where('user_requested', $this->id)->first();

        if ($friendship) {
            $friendship->update([
                'status' => 1,
            ]);

            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

if i add a friend it says friends but if i refresh the page its changing the status to 0, how can i fix this

Comment: ajax changes the page currently in your browser. Once you refresh, that instance of the page is destroyed, including any changes, and the page is reloaded from the server. So whatever logic you use on the server to load that status data when the page is first rendered needs to check the current friendship status in the data store and display the most recent value, rather than defaulting to 0. P.S. I can't prove it defaults to 0 because you didn't show any of that code or HTML, but that would be my guess.

Comment: my database changes to one 1

Comment: yes I know, that's my point. Clearly your page is not detecting that when it refreshes. Read the comment again.

Comment: So how can I fix that

Comment: Like I said already: "Whatever logic you use on the server to load that status data when the page is first rendered needs to check the current friendship status in the data store and display the most recent value instead of just 0". Did you not understand what I meant?